# How to get list of contact info from mailchimp?

Tags: java, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is there anyway to get the list of contact details from mailchimp using ecwid-mailchimp api?

```
 ListMembersMethod li = new ListMembersMethod();
 li.apikey = apikey;
 li.id = listId;
 li.limit = (int) memberCount;
 ListMembersResult execute = mailChimpClient.execute(li);
```

This code will just give me short info i.e. email and time strap. How to get full info of the members?

Comment: The answer here is probably "yes", but it's not clear what you need help with. What have you tried? Is there something that's not working?

Comment: @TooMuchPete thanks for quick response. I am trying to get all contact list from mailchimp and process it and insert into my local db. Using ecwid-mailchimp api i was able to connect to mailchimp but unable to get list of contact info. I would like to know is there any specific class or method to grab contact list from mailchimp? if yes could you please guide me?

Comment: What contacts are you looking for? Do you mean subscribers to your a list?

Comment: @TooMuchPete yes i want to get whole contact info from my mailchimp like emial, first name, second name, phone etc etc.

Comment: Do you have any code already? Can you describe what you have tried to do to accomplish this and how it didn't work?

Comment: @TooMuchPete I have edited my question. Thanks